# Customize CSS Stylesheet

Tags: css

first, take a look at the footer of my site

`http://www.twinklelittlestuff.com`

you may see the "Facebook" word with black color at the footer, and I want to change it to a

facebook logo + Instagram logo and put in on the bigger cloud at the right side.

I have played with the stylesheet css and the footer.tpl file, but still can't.

Maybe anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this images url **http://www.twinklelittlestuff.com/catalog/view/themes/kidsbasic/image/facebook.png**. it is failing

step 1
please open http://www.twinklelittlestuff.com/catalog/view/themes/kidsbasic/styleshhet/stylesheet.css
and go to line no 578.
replace with below lines

```
#signup-newsletter{border:1px solid#FF0000;color:#000000;display:block;font-family:'Pacifico','Lobster','Arimo',sans-serif,cursive;font-size:1.4em;font-weight:normal;height:100px;left:700px;line-height:40px;position:absolute;right:0;text-align:right;text-decoration:none;text-indent:-9999em;top:10px;width:100px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-icon-social-media/512/099303-facebook-logo-square.png" style="position:relative; left:670px;">

copy above line and paste here

<a id="signup-newsletter" href="http://www.facebook.com">
<!-- paste here the above two lines and remove the facebook text -->
</a>
```

[image]